# Concurrent Session IN Bigquery SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I have a data set that looks like this (I didn't do the timestamps justice, but imagine ~100 concurrent sessions in a 5-minute grain).

| SessionId | StartTime | EndTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1607843734-4000435-0027080AD | 2020-12-13 07:15:34 UTC | 2020-12-13 07:15:38 UTC |
| 1607874532-4000435-002239C78 | 2020-12-13 15:48:52 UTC | 2020-12-13 15:49:31 UTC |
| 1607888566-4000435-00014AE5A | 2020-12-13 19:42:45 UTC | 2020-12-13 19:45:11 UTC |
| 1607861896-4000435-00016767E | 2020-12-13 12:18:15 UTC | 2020-12-13 12:19:01 UTC |
| 1607847899-4000435-000172557 | 2020-12-13 08:24:58 UTC | 2020-12-13 08:35:38 UTC |

I am trying to figure out how to count the number of concurrent sessions using standard BigQuery SQL at a 5-minute grain, and possibly a one minute grain.

```
SELECT time, COUNT(*) concurrent
FROM (
 SELECT StartTime, EndTime
 FROM mytable
 WHERE start < '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
) a
JOIN
(
 SELECT time I dont know how to make a temp table with a 5 minute grain to join on) b
 ON a.x = b.x
 WHERE b.time < a.StartTime
AND b.time >= a.StartTime
GROUP BY 1
```

Can someone help? I am stuck ;(

Edit: I also have another timestamp field of when the record was written, so doesn't fall between the start and end times.

Comment: Please explain what "at a 5-minute grain" means.

Comment: Sorry i mean like over the course of a day, from 00:00:00 to 23:55:00 there are 287 5 minute intervals. Or if it were minutes you'd have 1399 one minute intervals. I am trying to count the sessions which are concurrent in those periods.@GordonLinoff

Comment: . . It is still not clear what that means.  What does sessions concurrent in 5-minute periods mean?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just truncate time as you need and then group by it. Assuming your field is of TIMESTAMP type:

For 1 minute interval:

```
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(time, MINUTE) as time_truncated,
  COUNT(*) as concurrent,
FROM mytable
GROUP BY time_truncated
ORDER BY time_truncated
```

For 5 minutes interval:

```
SELECT 
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(300 * DIV(UNIX_SECONDS(time), 300)) as time_truncated,
  COUNT(*) as concurrent,
FROM mytable
GROUP BY time_truncated
ORDER BY time_truncated
```